# Is it possible to calculate speed of light in a mixture of A and B, by knowing the speed of light in both medium A and B seperately?

Tags: speed-of-light, refraction

So we all know speed of light varies in different medium, which then makes me thinking is it possible for us to calculate the speed of light in a thoroughly mixed medium consists of X% of medium A and Y% of medium B?

I personally feels like such is possible, but I'm not quite sure how to achieve such, since we all know relativistic addition doesn't work like normal addition hence taking arithmetic mean isn't just simple as $X\times v_A+Y\times v_B$. And also since we're talking about velocity, I was thinking perhaps harmonic mean will be more appropriate, but also harmonic mean is indented to be apply when two medium are separated, not when mixed.

Comment: The speed of light is related to the relative permeability and permittivity of the medium. I think that mixing two different mediums results in a nontrivial mixture of their electromagnetic properties. This problem has nothing to do with relativistic addition of velocities, but rather the "addition" of their EM properties.

Comment: From a chemistry ground here. I would say not. I can't speak for some ideal medium A plus B one can define (sort of ideal gases or so)   but not in general and in practice.